# Connection Odoo and OPC_UA

Tags: odoo, opc-ua

I want to connect Odoo and OPC UA. On the website: https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/blog/unser-blog-5/meet-odoo-15-807, it is written that the IoT box now supports the OPC protocol.

The aim is to create a server using OPC UA and using data from Odoo.

Does anyone know how to do so?

Thanks!